# Sandboxed OSX App with COMMAND LINE helper gives 'unable to get root path'

Tags: macos, sandbox, code-signing, mac-app-store

I am building a Mac App that is bundled with the command tool 'unrar' to unrar some files. The app is sandboxed.

In xcode I copy the unrar command tool into the app's Resourse folder (with a subpath named 'exec'):

**Copy Files:**
*Destination: Resources -
Subpath: Exec*

After the copy phase I do a Run Script to set the entitlements and Code Signing as follows:

**Run Script:**
*Shell: /bin/sh*

```
LOCATION="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}"/"${CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH}"
IDENTITY="3rd Party Mac Developer Application: CompanyName."
codesign -f -s "$IDENTITY" --entitlements"/<path>/unrar.entitlements" "$LOCATION"/Resources/exec/unrar
```

In the app itself I use a NSTask to execute the unrar command:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"unrar" ofType:@"" inDirectory:@"exec"];

NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:filePath];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"e", rarfilepath,extractpath, nil]];
[_task launch];
```

The unrar.entitlements contains:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
<true/>
```

When running the app, everything works fine and the files get extracted.

But ... then when I check the systemlog I see the following message:

**secinitd[332]: unrar[94747]: unable to get root path for bundle of main executable: /Applications/App.app/Contents/Resources/exec/unrar**

The message does disappear when I don't run the above Run Script, but then the entitlements are not set for the 'unrar' command tool and Sandboxing fails.

I pulling my hear out for three days now what this message means and how to solve it, but I am out of ideas.

Searching google or stackoverflow doesn't help either.

Can anyone help me to solve this, please.

Thank you,
Andre.

(Sorry for all the text, but I am not allowed to post images yet.)

Comment: No one? Please help me out.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I've always placed my main and helper binary executables in `Contents/MacOS` but `Contents/Helpers` would do just as well.

These folders exclusively contain Mach-O executable binaries:

`Folder                           Executable`                            
    `_______________________________________________________________________`
 `Contents                         Top content directory of the bundle`
       `Contents/MacOS                   Helper apps and tools`
       `Contents/Frameworks              Frameworks, dylibs`
       `Contents/PlugIns                 Plug-ins, both loadable and Extensions`
       `Contents/XPCServices             XPC services`
       `Contents/Helpers                 Helper apps and tools`
       `Contents/Library/Automator       Automator actions`
       `Contents/Library/Spotlight       Spotlight importers`
       `Contents/Library/LoginItems      Installable login items`
       `Contents/Library/LaunchServices  Privileged helpers installed by ServiceManagement`

Other folders, such as `Contents/Resources` are for non-binary-exec files like scripts and data files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the unrar executable file must be located in

```
MySandboxApp.app/Contents/Helpers/unrar
```

The Resources folder is restricted to non-executable content.